# Error "object doesn't support this property or method: dbrowser.GetRoProperty"

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I was trying to run below script, but it's giving me an error that says:

> object doesn't support this property or method: "dbrowser.GetRoProperty"

```
SystemUtil.Run "iexplore.exe","http://usps.com/"
Set dbrowser = description.Create

dbrowser ("micclass").value = "Browser"

dbrowser("openurl").value = "https://www.usps.com"
dbrowser("title").value = "USPS - The United States Postal Service (U.S. Postal Service)"
print(dbrowser.getroproperty("title"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Description.Create`  is used to create a 0-based Properties collection object. The variable dbrowser is preceded by the Set statement. Usage of Set statement binds an object as a reference to another object. Therefore, dbrowser becomes an object reference to the description object represented by `Description.Create`

A description object does not have a stand-alone use, but coupled with the `ChildObjects` method, it becomes an extremely powerful approach in dealing with AUT’s objects .For More Info, check [link](http://relevantcodes.com/qtp-all-about-the-description-object-description-create/)

So the code should be like

```
SystemUtil.Run "iexplore.exe","http://usps.com/"

wait(10)
Set dbrowser = description.Create

dbrowser ("micclass").value = "Browser"
dbrowser("openurl").value = "https://www.usps.com"
dbrowser("title").value = "USPS.*"   ''Using Regular Expression here 

Set colObject = Desktop.ChildObjects( dbrowser )

Print (colObject(0).GetROProperty("title"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `dbrowser` object is of type `Description` not `Browser` you need to create a `Browser` object based on this description. Replace the last line with:

```
Print Browser(dbrowser).GetROProperty("title")
```

Note, there are two changes here

1. Using `Browser(dbrowser)`
2. Removing the parens from the `print` sub.

**Edit:** also note that descriptions are regular expressions by default so the parens in the `title` may cause problems, you should mark it as not regex.

```
dbrowser("title").RegularExpression = False
```